# Countdown JS not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, safari

I'm developing a website with a countdown.

The code works fine and the timer starts counting perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari the number shows NaN: NaN: NaN

Has anyone had this problem?

I'm using the JS Countdown: http://countdownjs.org/

Follow the code below:

Directive:

```
.directive('tempoPercorrido', function($interval){
     return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       var timeNow = new Date(attrs.tempoPercorrido);
       var units = countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS;
       var timespan = countdown(timeNow, null, units, 0, 0);                    
       function updateTme(){
       var timespan = countdown(timeNow, null, units, 0, 0);
       var dias = timespan.days <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.days.toString() : timespan.days.toString();
       var horas = timespan.hours <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.hours.toString() : timespan.hours.toString();
       var minutos = timespan.minutes <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.minutes.toString() : timespan.minutes.toString();
       var segundos = timespan.seconds <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.seconds.toString() : timespan.seconds.toString();  
       var contador = '<div class="dias circulo">'+ dias + '</div>'+
                      '<div class="horas circulo">'+ horas + '</div>'+
                      '<div class="minutos circulo">'+ minutos + '</div>'+
                      '<div class="segundos circulo">'+ segundos + '</div>';
                      //console.log(timespan);
                      $(element).html(contador);       
       }    
       updateTme();    
       $interval(function(){
                        updateTme();
       }, 1000);
       }
     }
})
```

Html:

```
<div class="horario_banner" tempo-percorrido="2017-09-15 10:00:00"></div>
```

Comment: Safari on Windows?

Comment: Safari on iphone